# LenB substitute in C#

Tags: c#, vb6

I have a program being ported from VB6 to C#.  It controls various equipment in an industrial setting, so it has to create and compute the length in bytes of messages sent to the hardware.  These messages are made from structs comprised of lots of primitive data types.

The original VB6 code used LenB extensively.   I'm thinking of using ***System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf()*** in its place.  Is this a good choice for a LenB substitute?

Also, the original program used LenB multiple places on 1 line, e.g.,

```
inputlen = LenB(sequenceBytes) - LenB(headerBytes) - LenB(crcBytes)
```

Replacing each one of those with a "system.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf" would make for a long, hard-to-read line.  C# has no preprocessor text macros, so is there some way to use a "using" statement or something to eliminate all those qualifiers to shorten the line?  Or should  just write a method?

Comment: Well what are the types of `sequenceBytes` and `headerBytes`? If they're `String` then they probably shouldn't be to start with - strings should be used for *text*, not arbitrary binary data. Rather than going for a direct substitution, you should work out what the program was trying to do and what it *should* have been doing.

Comment: Marshal.SizeOf() is most likely correct, given that you are really going to have to marshal those structures.  You'll also have to match the exact VB6 type sizes or the machine will do a backflip.  Clearly the length of a name should never be a good reason to avoid writing correct code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - as I said in the OP they are structs made from other primitive data types.   These structs may include strings, byte arrays, ints, other structs, etc.    We have no control over the composition of these variables -  they are set by specific pieces of hardware the program communicates with. But at the end of the day they are just big complex variables of some length and I need to know what that length, in bytes, is.

Comment: @user316117: Well that really depends on how you serialize the data, which will depend on the data in question. For example, for strings you need to know what encodings you're talking about. Just taking the raw size of the variables in memory may well be misleading, due to padding etc. The code which works out *exactly* how it's passing the data to the hardware should be responsible for working out the length as well, IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet The raw size of the variables in memory will be exactly what we want.   That's what LenB did and that's what we need here.  I can drop into unmanaged code to get it if I need to (the code that transfers these to the hardware does that anyway).  And all the structs that are defined in this application force byte-alignmwent with no padding.   But my question is what is the best way to know what the raw size in memory is.  Is system.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf the same as sizeof?  They're not spelled the same and I'm nervous about what they means by the size of a "type".

Comment: @user316117: `Marshal.SizeOf` is the size it will be when marshalled to unmanaged code. `sizeof` is the size in memory, but you can't use it with structs that contain reference types (such as strings).

Comment: The VB6 probably marshalls the strings as "ANSI" encoded.

Answer (score 4):

In C#, this expression evaluates to the size in bytes of the given `Type`:

```
sizeof(Type)
```

---

> C# has no preprocessor text macros, so is there some way to use a "using" statement or something to eliminate all those qualifiers to shorten the line? Or should just write a method?

Just add `System.Runtime.InteropServices` among the `using` clauses at the beginning of your code file:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Then you can call `Marshal.SizeOf()` directly without namespace qualification.

Comment: Actually this raises an interesting problem.  A Type is not the same as a variable because a variable can have different lengths at runtime.  Say it's a struct comprised of strings.  What does sizeof(String) return?    I need the actual runtime size of the variable.